# SQL Query Aggregate Error

Tags: aggregate-functions

I have written a query to get a list of users who have not logged anytime within the last 45 days. Here's the query I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(EMPLOYEE.EMP_CODE),EMP_TIME_DTL.DATE_ENTERED),EMPLOYEE.EMP_LNAME, EMPLOYEE.EMP_FNAME FROM EMP_TIME LEFT JOIN
EMP_TIME_DTL ON EMP_TIME.ET_ID = EMP_TIME_DTL.ET_ID LEFT JOIN
EMPLOYEE ON EMP_TIME.EMP_CODE = EMPLOYEE.EMP_CODE
WHERE  MAX(EMP_TIME_DTL.DATE_ENTERED) < DATEADD(day, -45, GETDATE())
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE.EMP_CODE, EMP_TIME_DTL.DATE_ENTERED,   EMPLOYEE.EMP_LNAME,    EMPLOYEE.EMP_FNAME
```

The EMP_TIME table contains the hours and the day they worked them. The EMP_TIME_DTL contains the date the employee actually entered the time. That table will have one row for each time entry made. I just want to find: each distinct EMP_CODE for those people who haven't entered time in the last 45 days.

The query I've written will get me those employees who haven't entered time in 45 days, but it also returns all the dates they entered time prior to that 45 day window.

So for example, if the last time John Doe entered time was on MAy 1st, then I want to return that date and his employee id. What I don't want is to return all the time he entered up until May 1st.

I've also tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(EMPLOYEE.EMP_CODE), (EMP_TIME_DTL.DATE_ENTERED),  EMPLOYEE.EMP_LNAME, EMPLOYEE.EMP_FNAME
FROM EMP_TIME LEFT JOIN
EMP_TIME_DTL ON EMP_TIME.ET_ID = EMP_TIME_DTL.ET_ID LEFT JOIN
EMPLOYEE ON EMP_TIME.EMP_CODE = EMPLOYEE.EMP_CODE
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE.EMP_CODE, EMP_TIME_DTL.DATE_ENTERED, EMPLOYEE.EMP_LNAME,     EMPLOYEE.EMP_FNAME
HAVING MAX(EMP_TIME_DTL.DATE_ENTERED) < DATEADD(day, -45, GETDATE())
```

Have also tried:

```
SELECT       MAX(EMP_TIME_DTL.ET_ID), MAX(EMP_TIME_DTL.SEQ_NBR),  (EMP_TIME.EMP_CODE), EMPLOYEE.EMP_LNAME, EMPLOYEE.EMP_FNAME,     (EMP_TIME_DTL.DATE_ENTERED)
FROM            EMP_TIME LEFT JOIN
EMPLOYEE ON EMP_TIME.EMP_CODE = EMPLOYEE.EMP_CODE LEFT JOIN
EMP_TIME_DTL ON EMP_TIME.ET_ID = EMP_TIME_DTL.ET_ID 
GROUP BY EMP_TIME.EMP_CODE, EMPLOYEE.EMP_LNAME, EMPLOYEE.EMP_FNAME,  (EMP_TIME_DTL.DATE_ENTERED), EMP_TIME_DTL.ET_ID, EMP_TIME_DTL.SEQ_NBR
HAVING MAX(EMP_TIME_DTL.DATE_ENTERED) < DATEADD(day, -45, GETDATE())
ORDER BY EMP_TIME.EMP_CODE, EMPLOYEE.EMP_LNAME, EMPLOYEE.EMP_FNAME,     EMP_TIME_DTL.ET_ID, EMP_TIME_DTL.SEQ_NBR, (EMP_TIME_DTL.DATE_ENTERED)
```

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Decided to utilize a CTE and that worked just fine!!

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use the following:

```
WITH EMP_TIME_CTE
(ET_ID, SEQ_NBR, EMP_CODE, LNAME, FNAME, DATE_ENTERED)
AS
(
SELECT       MAX(EMP_TIME_DTL.ET_ID), MAX(EMP_TIME_DTL.SEQ_NBR),     (EMP_TIME.EMP_CODE), EMPLOYEE.EMP_LNAME, EMPLOYEE.EMP_FNAME,     (EMP_TIME_DTL.DATE_ENTERED)
FROM            EMP_TIME LEFT JOIN
                     EMPLOYEE ON EMP_TIME.EMP_CODE     = EMPLOYEE.EMP_CODE LEFT JOIN
                     EMP_TIME_DTL ON EMP_TIME.ET_ID =     EMP_TIME_DTL.ET_ID 
                     WHERE EMPLOYEE.EMP_TERM_DATE     IS NULL
                     GROUP BY     EMP_TIME.EMP_CODE,     EMPLOYEE.EMP_LNAME, EMPLOYEE.EMP_FNAME, (EMP_TIME_DTL.DATE_ENTERED), EMP_TIME_DTL.ET_ID, EMP_TIME_DTL.SEQ_NBR
                     HAVING MAX(EMP_TIME_DTL.DATE_ENTERED) < DATEADD(day, -45, GETDATE())
                    -- ORDER BY EMP_TIME.EMP_CODE,     EMPLOYEE.EMP_LNAME, EMPLOYEE.EMP_FNAME, EMP_TIME_DTL.ET_ID,     EMP_TIME_DTL.SEQ_NBR, (EMP_TIME_DTL.DATE_ENTERED)
)
SELECT DISTINCT(EMP_CODE), FNAME + ' ' + LNAME AS FULL_NAME, MAX(DATE_ENTERED)     AS DATE_ENTERED
from EMP_TIME_CTE
GROUP BY EMP_CODE, FNAME, LNAME
HAVING MAX(DATE_ENTERED) < DATEADD(day, -45, GETDATE())
ORDER BY EMP_CODE asc
```